# Which is the best graphics drivers for NVIDIA GT 540M?

Tags: 16.04, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed NVIDIA 384.130 from additional drivers as 'Nouvea' wasn't working.
But, Ubuntu gets frozen after few minutes, I've to keep restarting it.

I saw many posts that Optimus wasn't supported in the past.
What's the current state?
Which drivers should I use?

Comment: We wont be able to answer this... it depends on more than just the driver. "But, Ubuntu gets frozen after few minutes" That does not mean it is related to the nvidia. Random crashes often are related to memory. ---ALL---  available drivers in additional resources are tested and should work. Generally it is a matter of performance that decides what you pick. "Which drivers should I use?" The one that is listed as "open source tested"  (that can be more than 1 ;-) ) and optional "closed source tested" if you like some more options.

Comment: .. regarding crashes: check the log viewer for words like CRITICAL, ERROR, bug. immenent and crash

Comment: It wasn't freezing before I installed NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: I'll check for the log!